# Is it necessary for a kernel function to have a corresponding feature map?

Tags: machine-learning, kernel, svm

I have read about linear kernels, polynomial kernels, etc. Then I wondered whether if it's needed to for a kernel function to have a feature map.

Comment: Not a *programming* question, hence arguably off-topic here; maybe suited for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).